# Acumatica API. Fetch products

Tags: api, acumatica

What endpoints are used to fetch from Acumatica product data. Theoretically it should be `/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem`, however there no info about assigned categories, attributes, complex product information

Comment: If you take a look at the StockItem entity in the endpoint. Is the information that you want present in the top level entity or in sub entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default endpoint provides the ability to get the following information from the Stock Items page
[image]

The main problem with this page is that Acumatica doesn't allow to request more than one array type detail at a time and as you can see on the screenshot almost all details are arrays. So you will have to request each one separately.

For example, you can get items with their Categories by sending the following GET request:

```
entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$expand=Categories
```

but at the same time, it is a little tricky to get Attributes, because you will need to send a PUT request with InventoryID for getting Attributes of the Item:

Request: `entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$expand=Attributes`
Body:

```
{
    "InventoryID" : {
        "value" : "AACOMPUT01"
    }
}
```

If you need to be able to get other information from this page you will need to extend endpoint, entity and add additional Views and Fields.

Comment: Many thanks for very clear answer!! Two more questions: 1. To fetch Categories + Attributes - is it always two separate requests? 2. According to documentation to fetch files (assigned images), is it the only way to fetch them by providing InventoryID? What if I need to pull 1000 products. It means that I should: 1. Retrieve all products 2. Retrieve each product by InventoryID to fetch attributes and files. 3. Fetch each file separately. It means that I should do 2000 API requests?

Comment: @zhartaunik 1. Yes, you have to do 2 separate requests for getting Categories + Attributes. You can fetch Categories with all the items by one requests, but you will have to send a separate request for each item for Attributes. 2. No, if you need to retrieve all products with Attributes and Files it will take you 3001 (1 for all items + 1000 for attributes + 1000 for getting record by key + 1000 for getting actual file) requests for 1000 items. Here is help article regarding file attachments https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b1bc82ee-ae6b-442a-a369-863d98f14630

Comment: @zhartaunik technically you can get all the items and then start sending request with several threads.

Comment: @zhartaunik I have recently noticed that for some Entities like Contact the system returns Attributes with values in the case when the request is a simple get for all the records and $expand= Attributes